# Cannot connect to switch from VPN

Tags: networking, vpn, firewall, switch

I have got network:

[image]

The problem is i can not connect from VPN to Netis. I can ping to Netis from MikroTik and computer and access Netis managment site from computer, but I can not ping and access to Netis when I am connected by VPN to Mikrotik. When I am connected by VPN I can ping and remote access to computer. I think the reason is in Netis firewall who don`t allow to access from VPN subnet, but in Netis firewall configuration everything is off.

Thanks for any ideas and sorry for poor english :)

Comment: Can you change your Open VPN subnet to 192.168.68.x?  Everything is on the 192.168.68.x subnet and it seems likely that is there is not a connection.

Answer (score 0):

Can you change your Open VPN subnet to `192.168.68.x`? Everything is on the `192.168.68.x` subnet and it seems likely that is there is not a connection….. ps hate slow data